# Facebook FQL returns empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to use FQL to fetch the newsfeed from a page.
(That means, all messages that are posted by pages that are followed by my page.)

In order to do this, I came up with following FQL query:

```sql
select 
    message, 
    attachment, 
    description, 
    action_links, 
    actor_id, 
    comment_info, 
    created_time, 
    permalink, 
    post_id, 
    share_count, 
    type
from 
    stream 
where 
    source_id in (select page_id from page_fan where uid = 272752359511949) and 
    actor_id in (select page_id from page_fan where uid = 272752359511949)
```

Works like a charm when I test it in the FQL tool.

However, as soon as I try to use it with my own access token, I get an empty array.

I have checked all permissions and I have everything I need. In the tool, when I disable all extra permissions, I still get the result set. (All information is public anyway.)

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?
Why can't I access this information when using my app's access token?

**Edit:** More information:

**Edit 2:** A very strange thing happened a few days ago: the whole thing started working. Suddenly, I started receiving updates from pages that we liked about a month ago. Pages that we liked recently, however, still do not appear in the query. I really think this has something to do with caching.

**My access token (as received from authenticating)**

```
App ID: 183224428519306 : Cloudwalkers
User ID:    100003382483550 : Ken Borteel
Issued: 1375013777 (on Sunday)
Expires:    Never
Valid:  True
Origin: Web
Scopes: create_note manage_pages photo_upload 
            publish_actions publish_stream read_stream 
            share_item status_update video_upload
```

=> Returns empty array

**TEST ACCESS TOKEN:**

```
App ID: 145634995501895 : Graph API Explorer
User ID:    644032185 : Thijs Van der Schaeghe
Issued: Unknown
Expires:    1375282800 (in about an hour)
Valid:  True
Origin: Web
Scopes:
```

**RETURNS everything I need.**

I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: _“Why can't I access this information when using my app's access token?”_ – do you actually mean an _app_ access token, or a _user_ access token (for a user using your app)?

Comment: User access token, so that's the token I receive after a user logs in. I also extend the access token to unlimited use. (extended access token)

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the `access token`. Add the access_token while making your query and see if it works!

Comment: Yea, I'm sure I have a valid access token.
When I fetch a new access token in the FQL tool, it works fine. When I use my own access token (also in the tool) I get an empty array. It looks a lot like caching, but the caching seems to be very invalid...)

Comment: try to use the token of the fql tool in your code and see if it works.

Comment: That means the access token you are using in your code is not correct. Pls check that

Comment: There's no such user access token, that `never expires`, its the App's access token you are using (both are different). So, your access token is not correct! Details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)

Comment: After authentication, I do this to fetch the access key:
`$this->facebook->setExtendedAccessToken ();
$this->setSetting ('access_token', $this->facebook->getAccessToken ());`

Comment: A very strange thing happened a few days ago: the whole thing started working. Suddenly, I started receiving updates from pages that we liked about a month ago. Pages that we liked recently, however, still do not appear in the query. I **really** think this has something to do with caching.